# Azure Logic App - Parse JSON with dynamic key/name

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

just want to know if and how I can parse a HTTP response with a dynamic name in a JSON?
I used the [Azure Management API to receive the managed identities (*system- and user assigned managed identities*)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) to receive all managed identities.
With a foreach I am iterating the results.

If a resource has a `system assigned managed identity` and `user assigned managed identity`, the response looks like this:

```
{
  "principalId": "<principalId1>",
  "tenantId": "<tenantId>",
  "type": "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": {
    "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<userAssignedIdentitiesName>": {
      "principalId": "<principalId2>",
      "clientId": "<clientId>"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to get the `<principalId2>`.
Unfortunately, the `Name` of the object is dynamic related to the scope of the resource `/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<userAssignedIdentitiesName>`.

[image]

How can I parse the JSON to receive the needed `<principalId2>`?
For all other responses I can easily use the `Data operations` `Parse JSON` with the payload I inserted from the HTTP response.
Is there a way to use a wildcard? Otherwise, could I somehow just select the first object of `userAssignedIdentities` to receive the needed value?

Comment: Is it completely dynamic or do you know the values it will potentially be? I’m asking but I’m 95% sure it’s the former and just want to be sure.

Comment: Hey, it is somehow dynamic. This was the reason why I asked if wildcards in `Parse Json` are supported. Is looks like this `/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<userAssignedIdentitiesName>`. Only the `subscriptionId`, `ResourceGroupName` and `userAssignedIdentitiesName` is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should work for you.  This is the flow I tested with ...

[image: Flow]

**Initialise JSON**

Your JSON as a **string**, how you do that in your solution may differ slightly.

**Initialize XPath Result**

Defined as an **Array** and the expression is ...

```
xpath(xml(json(concat('{ root: ', replace(variables('JSON'), 'PrincipalId', 'principalId'), '}'))), '(//principalId)[2]')
```

**Initialize Result**

A bit more work again but defined as a **String** and the expression is ...

```
array(xpath(xml(base64ToString(variables('XPath Result')[0]?['$content'])), '//text()'))[0]
```

The end result should be your value ...

[image: Result]

Comment: Just another question cause the ARM API is responding strange.. It seems that it is case sensitive to identify the name. Sometimes the API is responding, for whatever reason, with `PrincipalId` instead of `principalId`. Then it won't find the value. I mean I can use as a workaround a if-condition, but you might have also an answer on this?

Comment: I've been dicking around with XPath to see if I can get it to work but it doesn't like anything I give it.  Therefore, the easiest thing to do would be to set any `PrincipleId` text to lower case and go from there.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Check the updated answer for the middle `Initialize XPath Result` step in the flow.  Tested and it worked for me, you may need to test further with real data but I suspect it will be ok.  I also updated the last step, I overcooked the solution.

Comment: I just saw, that when more than one `userAssignedIdentities` are in the results the `foreach` for `xPath Result` will automatically decode the `base64` to `string`. In this case, you need to use `array(xpath(xml(outputs('Compose_7')), '//text()'))[0]` to get the text within the xml-attribute `<principalId></principalId>`

Comment: Oh ok, nice.  Yeah, I could only work on what you gave me so you've managed to take it a step further with real data.